# Yii2 in Yii1 application

Tags: yii2

I already ran `yii2` in `yii1` application according to [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1). It works, but what kind of functionality of `yii2`, can I use?

Can I create new controllers, modules or ActiveRecords and so on as in `yii2`?

Comment: Adding the correct namespace and extending or referring to the class in the correct way yes. I'm not saying is easy but yes you can